# Debugging HTML in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a project with D3 in a Jupyter notebook, so I'm implementing it through Javascript and HTML cells. However, I can't get any output from `console.log()` where  `<script>` tags are in `%%html` cells. What is the best way to debug this, or is best practice creating separate Javascript cells and importing those into my HTML cells?